# How can i add a While loop to detect errors in the input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, i am trying to write a code to not only do arithmetic equations, but also, give feedback if there is an error as well as give me 3 tries max. any advice?

```
arithmetic=input("Enter an arithmetic operation:")
arithmetic= arithmetic.replace(" ", "")  
w=arithmetic.split('/')
x= arithmetic.split('-')  
y=arithmetic.split('+')
z=arithmetic.split('*')
if ("+" in arithmetic):
    a= int(y[0])
    b= int(y[1])
    sum = a + b
    print("The result is = " + str(sum))
elif ("*" in arithmetic):
    a= int(z[0])
    b= int(z[1])
    result = a * b
    print("The result is = " + str(result))            
elif ("/" in arithmetic):
    a= int(w[0])
    b= int(w[1])
    result = a / b
    result = round(result,3)
    print("The result is = " + str(result)) 
    
elif ("-" in arithmetic) and (len(x)==3):  
    a= int(x[1])
    b= int(x[2])
    result = a + b                    
    result = result  * (-1)
    print("The result is = " + str(result))    
    
elif ("-" in arithmetic) and (len(x)==2):  
    a= int(x[0])
    b= int(x[1])  
    result = a - b
    print("The result is = " + str(result)) 
#tries = 0
#while(tries  < 3):
#    arithmetic=input("Enter an arithmetic operation:")
#    match = arithmetic.find('+')
#    print(match)
#    if(match == -1): 
#        print ("Invalid")
#        tries += 1
#    else:
#        tries= 3
```

I tried to add the while in the beginning. However, when i put an input such as `11` and `12` without the `+` sign, it just printed the input without giving me an error. why is that?

Comment: (1) The shown code does nothing if the input doesn't contain one of the expected operators. Maybe a final "else" can help. (2) Decide which Python version you want to use and remove one tag from the question.

Comment: not sure what you mean in (1), so if i put `match= arithmetic.find('+')` then `if (match==-1)` `print ('invalid')`. doesn't that mean if the + was not found to print invalid? when i type the equation without the plus. i still do not get the invalid message which is weird to me.

Comment: Right, you should get the "invalid" with this code. Which output does the `print(match)` produce?

Comment: gives me -1, i looked closely into your message and i missed the part when you said to include an else at the end. now it works. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
tries = 0

while tries < 3:
    arithmetic = input("Enter an arithmetic operation:")
    arithmetic = arithmetic.replace(" ", "")
    w = arithmetic.split('/')
    x = arithmetic.split('-')
    y = arithmetic.split('+')
    z = arithmetic.split('*')
    try:
        if ("+" in arithmetic):
            a = int(y[0])
            b = int(y[1])
            sum = a + b
            print("The result is = " + str(sum))
        elif ("*" in arithmetic):
            a = int(z[0])
            b = int(z[1])
            result = a * b
            print("The result is = " + str(result))
        elif ("/" in arithmetic):
            a = int(w[0])
            b = int(w[1])
            result = a / b
            result = round(result, 3)
            print("The result is = " + str(result))

        elif ("-" in arithmetic) and (len(x) == 3):
            a = int(x[1])
            b = int(x[2])
            result = a + b
            result = result * (-1)
            print("The result is = " + str(result))
        elif ("-" in arithmetic) and (len(x) == 2):
            a = int(x[0])
            b = int(x[1])
            result = a - b
            print("The result is = " + str(result))
        else:
            print("Invalid")
            tries += 1
            continue
        break
    except ValueError:  # for case split not working good due cases like first input is a negative number
        print("Invalid")
        tries += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. so there was no need to add conditions such as not finding + since anything else is an error. not sure how i didn't think of that hehe

Comment: currently, the code works with all equations, except when i try to input `-a "space" b`, it gives me    `a= int(x[0])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: a workaround is to add a try except block for this case. i edited answer with this.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your if / else if chain, just add:

```
else:
    print("invalid")
    tries += 1
```

Replace everything you have inside your while loop currently with the uncommented code above it and that should work.